notifee.displayNotification(*) 'notification.id' invalid notification ID, expected a unique string value
We're seeing

notifee.displayNotification(*) 'notification.id' invalid notification ID, expected a unique string value.

a lot on bugsnag. Has anyone seen this?
Here's the .displayNotification code:
          notificationListener = messaging().onMessage(async (notification) => {
            const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
              id: 'default',
              name: 'Default Channel',
              importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
              description: 'Display notification while in foreground',
            })

            notifee.displayNotification({
              id: notification.messageId,
              title: notification.notification?.title,
              body: notification.notification?.body,
              data: notification.data,
              android: {
                sound: 'default',
                channelId: channelId,
                smallIcon: 'ic_stat_icon_push_notification',
                importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH,
              },
              ios: {
                sound: 'default',
              },
            })
          })

